# Foreach não retorna nada

Tags: php, pdo, foreach

Tenho uma Query do banco de dados que me retorna um objeto
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 3
            [status] => pendente
            [tarefa] => tomar suco
        )

```
[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 17
        [status] => pendente
        [tarefa] => lavar pneu
    )
```

Só que no momento do foreach para exibir os dados na tela, está retornando somente

```
 $tarefa){ ?>()
```

segue o foreach:

```
  <? foreach($tarefas as $indice => $tarefa){ ?>

      <?= $tarefa->tarefa?> (<?= $tarefa->status ?>)
<? } ?>
```

(as tags PHP são por que estão no arquivo HTML)

Comment: Seu servidor **PHP** identifica arquivos html como arquivos php? Qual a extensão do arquivo onde está esse código .html ou .php?

Comment: `var_dump($tarefas);` mostra o que ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
foreach ($stdClass as $key => $value) {
    $resp[] = $key.' - '.$value;
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($resp);
echo "</pre>";

Array
(
    [0] => ID - 17
    [1] => STATUS - PENDENTE
    [2] => TAREFA - LAVAR PNEU
)
```

Comment: O erro estava no parâmetro de busca da query, msm assim vlw muito! xD

Answer (score -2):

Use a seguinte função *php* para converter *stdClass* para *array*

```
get_object_vars($data)
```